# Decoding error with async/await function to fetch Data

Tags: json, swift, async-await, decoding

Im trying to decode JSON-Data from an API asynchronously, but somehow I get an error while decoding.

Here is an example of a JSON response which I then put into a Quote inside a Swift struct:

```
 [
   {
     "Code": "BAS",
     "Exchange": "XETRA",
     "Name": "BASF SE NA O.N.",
     "Type": "Common Stock",
     "ISIN": "DE000BASF111",
     "previousClose": 43.11,
     "previousCloseDate": "2023-06-27",
     "countryName": "Germany",
     "currencyCode": "EUR"
   },
   {
     "Code": "BAS",
     "Exchange": "F",
     "Name": "BASF SE",
     "Type": "Common Stock",
     "ISIN": "DE000BASF111",
     "previousClose": 43.275,
     "previousCloseDate": "2023-06-27",
     "countryName": "Germany",
     "currencyCode": "EUR"
   }
 ]

struct Quote: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { return UUID() }
    let code: String
    let exchange: String
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let isin: String
    let price: Double
    let closeDate: String
    let country: String
    let currency: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case exchange = "Exchange"
        case name = "Name"
        case type = "Type"
        case isin = "ISIN"
        case price = "previousClose"
        case closeDate = "previousCloseDate"
        case country = "countryName"
        case currency = "currencyCode"
    }
}
```

Then I tried to add a SearchManager:

```
@Observable
final class SearchManager {
    var searchResults = [Quote]()
    var error: Error? = nil
    private(set) var isSearching = false
    
    init() {
        loadData(keyword: "BASF")
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchSecuritiesAsync(keyword: String) async throws {
        
        isSearching = true
        defer { isSearching = false }
        
        do {
            guard let encodedKeyword = keyword.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to encode keyword")
                return
            }
            
            guard let url = URL(string: API.searchUrl(for: encodedKeyword)) else { throw GeneralSearchError.invalidURL }
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { throw GeneralSearchError.serverError }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let securities = try? decoder.decode([Quote].self, from: data) else {
                print("error")
            return
            }
            self.searchResults = securities
        } catch {
            self.error = error
        }
    }
    
    func loadData(keyword: String) {
        Task {
            try await fetchSecuritiesAsync(keyword: keyword)
            print(searchResults)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to find the error with different print statements and got to the decoding part of the function:

```
guard let securities = try? decoder.decode([Quote].self, from: data) else {
                print("error")
            return
            }
```

with the init I get the following output in the console:

> error
> []
> error
> []

But the output should be similar to the example above.
I can't figure out what's wrong how I tried to decode the JSON

Changing the code to the following:

```
@MainActor
    func fetchSecuritiesAsync(keyword: String) async throws {
        
        isSearching = true
        defer { isSearching = false }
        
        do {
//            guard let encodedKeyword = keyword.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
//                print("DEBUG: Failed to encode keyword")
//                return
//            }
            let url = URL(string: API.searchUrl(for: keyword))!
         //   guard let url = URL(string: API.searchUrl(for: keyword)) else { throw GeneralSearchError.invalidURL }
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nix")
            guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { throw GeneralSearchError.serverError }
            searchResults = try JSONDecoder().decode([GeneralSearch].self, from: data)
          //  self.searchResults = securities
        } catch {
            self.error = error
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Gives this output to the console with a decoding error at the bottom:

> [{"Code":"BASF","Exchange":"NSE","Name":"BASF India
> Limited","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"INE373A01013","previousClose":2595.65,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"India","currencyCode":"INR"},{"Code":"BASFY","Exchange":"US","Name":"BASF
> SE ADR","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"US0552625057","previousClose":11.84,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"USA","currencyCode":"USD"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"XETRA","Name":"BASF
> SE NA O.N.","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":43.11,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"0BFA","Exchange":"LSE","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":42.935,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"UK","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"F","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":43.275,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"STU","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.215,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BFFAF","Exchange":"US","Name":"BASF
> SE NA O.N.","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":47.14,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"USA","currencyCode":"USD"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"HM","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.265,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"MU","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.195,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"DU","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.085,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"BE","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.245,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"HA","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.265,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BASN","Exchange":"MX","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":869.36,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-26","countryName":"Mexico","currencyCode":"MXN"},{"Code":"BASA","Exchange":"F","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"US0552625057","previousClose":10.5,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BASA","Exchange":"STU","Name":"Basf
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":10.5,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"}]
> valueNotFound(Swift.Array<Swift.String>,
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
> 3", intValue: 3), CodingKeys(stringValue: "ISIN", intValue: nil)],
> debugDescription: "Cannot get unkeyed decoding container -- found null
> value instead", underlyingError: nil)) []
>
> [{"Code":"BASF","Exchange":"NSE","Name":"BASF India
> Limited","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"INE373A01013","previousClose":2595.65,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"India","currencyCode":"INR"},{"Code":"BASFY","Exchange":"US","Name":"BASF
> SE ADR","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"US0552625057","previousClose":11.84,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"USA","currencyCode":"USD"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"XETRA","Name":"BASF
> SE NA O.N.","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":43.11,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"0BFA","Exchange":"LSE","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":42.935,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"UK","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"F","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":43.275,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"STU","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.215,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BFFAF","Exchange":"US","Name":"BASF
> SE NA O.N.","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":47.14,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"USA","currencyCode":"USD"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"HM","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.265,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"MU","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.195,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"DU","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.085,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"BE","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.245,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BAS","Exchange":"HA","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":43.265,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BASN","Exchange":"MX","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"DE000BASF111","previousClose":869.36,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-26","countryName":"Mexico","currencyCode":"MXN"},{"Code":"BASA","Exchange":"F","Name":"BASF
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":"US0552625057","previousClose":10.5,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"Code":"BASA","Exchange":"STU","Name":"Basf
> SE","Type":"Common
> Stock","ISIN":null,"previousClose":10.5,"previousCloseDate":"2023-06-27","countryName":"Germany","currencyCode":"EUR"}]
> valueNotFound(Swift.Array<Swift.String>,
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
> 3", intValue: 3), CodingKeys(stringValue: "ISIN", intValue: nil)],
> debugDescription: "Cannot get unkeyed decoding container -- found null
> value instead", underlyingError: nil)) []

Comment: Not the point of the question but `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Thank you, so it's unnecessary?

Comment: No, it is necessary but it's not the correct way to URL encode.

Comment: Also note that your function `throws` but you are actually swallowing the error inside the function. Your `fetchSecuritiesAsync` never throws an error.

Comment: could you try using:
`searchResults = try decoder.decode([Quote].self, from: data)`
and `print(error)` in the `catch{...}`.
Also add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just after
 `let (data, response) = try await ...`, and let us know what it prints.

Comment: I edited the code and indeed some of the data is fetched correctly but there is a decoding error displayed at the bottom of the list

Comment: In `struct Quote`, try using `let isin: String?` and look at the docs to see what other properties need to be optional, then add `?` to them. Note you should be decoding `[Quote].self`, not `[GeneralSearch].self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included output in which you have apparently replaced `try?` with `try`, showing you this error message:

> valueNotFound(Swift.Array<Swift.String>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 3", intValue: 3), CodingKeys(stringValue: "ISIN", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Cannot get unkeyed decoding container -- found null value instead", underlyingError: nil))

That is telling you that the fourth item does not have a value for `ISIN`. And if we look at the JSON, you can see that the fourth item indeed supplied `null` for `ISIN`:

```json
{
    "Code": "0BFA",
    "Exchange": "LSE",
    "Name": "BASF SE",
    "Type": "Common Stock",
    "ISIN": null,
    "previousClose": 42.935,
    "previousCloseDate": "2023-06-27",
    "countryName": "UK",
    "currencyCode": "EUR"
}
```

Thus, you have to make `isin` property optional:

```swift
let isin: String?
```